# MySQL: How to select max/min time data between specific time range with some conditions?

Tags: mysql, date, time, range

I have a set of data like this table:

```
ID    sTime                  sDate       Pin    Name
29    5/4/2015 7:07:05 AM    5/4/2015    118    Sigit
30    5/4/2015 7:07:08 AM    5/4/2015    118    Sigit
31    5/4/2015 7:12:31 AM    5/4/2015    184    Aprilia
32    5/4/2015 7:13:20 AM    5/4/2015    182    Siska
33    5/4/2015 7:17:12 AM    5/4/2015    102    Sugandi
34    5/4/2015 7:17:14 AM    5/4/2015    102    Sugandi
35    5/4/2015 7:17:28 AM    5/4/2015    29     Ade
36    5/4/2015 7:17:33 AM    5/4/2015    164    Hendrik
37    5/4/2015 7:17:37 AM    5/4/2015    104    Rahmat
38    5/4/2015 7:17:41 AM    5/4/2015    67     Endang
39    5/4/2015 7:17:45 AM    5/4/2015    43     Dedy
40    5/4/2015 7:17:47 AM    5/4/2015    43     Dedy
41    5/4/2015 7:18:16 AM    5/4/2015    12     Toni
42    5/4/2015 7:19:16 AM    5/4/2015    115    Dedi
43    5/4/2015 7:20:14 AM    5/4/2015    30     Dadang
44    5/4/2015 7:21:58 AM    5/4/2015    165    Muammad
45    5/4/2015 7:22:00 AM    5/4/2015    165    Muammad
46    5/4/2015 7:22:02 AM    5/4/2015    165    Muammad
47    5/4/2015 7:22:04 AM    5/4/2015    165    Muammad
151   5/4/2015 4:03:53 PM    5/4/2015    43     Dedy
152   5/4/2015 4:03:58 PM    5/4/2015    164    Hendrik
153   5/4/2015 4:04:04 PM    5/4/2015    26     Syamsuddin
154   5/4/2015 4:04:09 PM    5/4/2015    26     Syamsuddin
155   5/4/2015 4:04:21 PM    5/4/2015    19     Eddy
156   5/4/2015 4:04:32 PM    5/4/2015    133    Haetami
157   5/4/2015 4:04:38 PM    5/4/2015    92     Budi
158   5/4/2015 4:05:05 PM    5/4/2015    131    Rosadi
159   5/4/2015 4:05:29 PM    5/4/2015    115    Dedi
160   5/4/2015 4:05:48 PM    5/4/2015    80     Cahya
161   5/4/2015 4:05:54 PM    5/4/2015    125    Yahya
```

conditions for each name and each day:

- select the **earliest sTime value** between hour 07.00 and 08.30
- select the **latest sTime value** between hour 16.00 and 17.15 (04.00 PM - 05.15 PM)

the selected data:

```
ID    sTime                  sDate       Pin    Name
29    5/4/2015 7:07:05 AM    5/4/2015    118    Sigit
31    5/4/2015 7:12:31 AM    5/4/2015    184    Aprilia
32    5/4/2015 7:13:20 AM    5/4/2015    182    Siska
33    5/4/2015 7:17:12 AM    5/4/2015    102    Sugandi
35    5/4/2015 7:17:28 AM    5/4/2015    29     Ade
36    5/4/2015 7:17:33 AM    5/4/2015    164    Hendrik
37    5/4/2015 7:17:37 AM    5/4/2015    104    Rahmat
38    5/4/2015 7:17:41 AM    5/4/2015    67     Endang
39    5/4/2015 7:17:45 AM    5/4/2015    43     Dedy
41    5/4/2015 7:18:16 AM    5/4/2015    12     Toni
42    5/4/2015 7:19:16 AM    5/4/2015    115    Dedi
43    5/4/2015 7:20:14 AM    5/4/2015    30     Dadang
44    5/4/2015 7:21:58 AM    5/4/2015    165    Muammad
151   5/4/2015 4:03:53 PM    5/4/2015    43     Dedy
152   5/4/2015 4:03:58 PM    5/4/2015    164    Hendrik
154   5/4/2015 4:04:09 PM    5/4/2015    26     Syamsuddin
155   5/4/2015 4:04:21 PM    5/4/2015    19     Eddy
156   5/4/2015 4:04:32 PM    5/4/2015    133    Haetami
157   5/4/2015 4:04:38 PM    5/4/2015    92     Budi
158   5/4/2015 4:05:05 PM    5/4/2015    131    Rosadi
159   5/4/2015 4:05:29 PM    5/4/2015    115    Dedi
160   5/4/2015 4:05:48 PM    5/4/2015    80     Cahya
161   5/4/2015 4:05:54 PM    5/4/2015    125    Yahya
```

and display it like this table:

```
Name        Date        In Time    Out Time
Sigit       5/4/2015    7:07:05
Aprilia     5/4/2015    7:12:31
Dedy        5/4/2015    7:17:45    16:03:53
Dedi        5/4/2015    7:19:16    16:05:29
Cahya       5/4/2015               16:05:48
Yahya       5/4/2015               16:05:54
```

I have crawled over for any queries like this but I can't find the exact solution to it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's the datatype of `sTime`?

Comment: it's CHAR(24) like you assumed.. and thanks for the solution, working on it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes `sTime` is a character string in the format you showed.

```
SELECT name, date, IFNULL(intime, '') `In Time`, IFNULL(outtime, '') `Out Time`
FROM (
    SELECT name, sdate AS date, 
        MIN(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sTime, ' ', -2) BETWEEN '7:00:00 AM' AND '8:30:00 AM', 
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sTime, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 
                NULL)) AS intime,
        MAX(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sTime, ' ', -2) BETWEEN '4:00:00 PM' AND '5:15:00 PM', 
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sTime, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 

                NULL)) AS outtime
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY name, sdate
    HAVING intime IS NOT NULL OR outtime IS NOT NULL
    ) AS x
ORDER BY intime IS NULL, intime, outtime
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d352a/6)